# Plotting two figures from two xarrays side by side

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray, cartopy

I'm trying to plot two subplots side by side.
Each subplot is a variable from xarray, and the plot is a projection.

My plotting function is:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy

def plot_avg(data, **kwargs):


    ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Orthographic(central_latitude=-90.0))

    ax.coastlines(resolution='10m',zorder=3)
    ax.gridlines(color='gray')
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, zorder=1,facecolor=cartopy.feature.COLORS['land_alt1'])
    data.plot(ax = ax, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
               vmin = 34.4 , vmax=35.81 , levels=17 ,
               cmap=Becki, cbar_kwargs={'shrink': 0.3})
```

And the main code is:

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
plot_avg(var1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
plot_avg(var2)
```

But for some reason I can't do it, i always get one plot with two colorbars:

[image]

What can I do differently? I'm having a hard time with the plot objects from the xarray.

The sample data files for plotting are here:
[netcdf files](https://gofile.io/?c=EQUCsY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create too many axes here. Make sure to only create the two axes you want to use.

```
def plot_avg(data, ax, **kwargs):
    ax.coastlines(resolution='10m',zorder=3)
    ax.gridlines(color='gray')
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, zorder=1,facecolor=cartopy.feature.COLORS['land_alt1'])
    data.plot(ax = ax, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
               vmin = 34.4 , vmax=35.81 , levels=17 ,
               cmap=Becki, cbar_kwargs={'shrink': 0.3})

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection=ccrs.Orthographic(central_latitude=-90.0))
plot_avg(var1, ax1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection=ccrs.Orthographic(central_latitude=-90.0))
plot_avg(var2, ax2)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but for some reason, the two plots now are overlapping each other in a strange way: https://ibb.co/LJnvsbc

Comment: Oh yes, I blindly copied from your question, now it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `ax` as a parameter to your function:

```
def plot_avg(data, ax, **kwargs):


    ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Orthographic(central_latitude=-90.0))

    ax.coastlines(resolution='10m',zorder=3)
    ax.gridlines(color='gray')
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, zorder=1,facecolor=cartopy.feature.COLORS['land_alt1'])
    data.plot(ax = ax, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
               vmin = 34.4 , vmax=35.81 , levels=17 ,
               cmap=Becki, cbar_kwargs={'shrink': 0.3})
```

Then pass the `ax` you create into the function call:

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
plot_avg(var1, ax1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
plot_avg(var2, ax2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately - It's behaving in the same way. One plot, two colorbars

Comment: Is there a chance your dataset in `var2` is broken? What happens if you try plotting var1 twice?